# Visual Studio C++ link with different symbol “@PBD@Z” vs “@PEBD@Z”

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am link a third-party library. When I link it to an exe, it is ok, the symbol name ends with "@PBD@Z”. But If I link it in my static library, then link my static library to an exe, I got unresolved symbol which ends with “@PEBD@Z”. I grep the library, there is "@PBD@Z” symbol. I can not figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Most likely that library has a #define somewhere to switch linking to static. This is common. Boost log has the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason. PEBD is x64 const char* symbol, PBD is win32 const char* symbol, my problem is I am linking x64 to win32 lib.